Perform different aggregation functions on different rows of the output returned by group by clause
I came across this question on a coding platform
One single table is given. It is of the following format:
Temperature_records



Record_date
Data_type
Data_value




2020-07-01
max
92


2020-07-01
min
71


2020-07-01
avg
74


2020-07-02
max
90


2020-07-02
min
67


2020-07-02
avg
77



The table consists of the minimum, maximum and average temperature readings for each day for six months in 2020. We need to calculate the monthly minimum, monthly average, monthly maximum temperatures. The output should be like this: (The min, max and avg temperatures should be rounded off to the nearest integer)



Month
Min
Max
Avg




7
92
99
95


8
91
100
94



Now, I have used the following query:
select table1.month, table1.data_type, table1.data_value
from (
    select substring(record_date, 6, 2) as "month", data_type, data_value
    from temperature_records
) table1
order by table1.month, table1.data_type;

This query gives me an output that looks like this:



Month
data_type
data_value




7
avg
97


7
avg
98



It returns the month-wise records
Now if I group the records by (month, data_type), then I need to perform an aggregation function on the records depending on their data_type. How can I do that?
Also, how can I return the records according the desired output format?

Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Do you store dates in a char/varchar column?!? Use a proper data data type instead.

No need to involve year? What's expected to happen when your table has data for more than one year?

The problem on the coding platform stored the date in a varchar column. I should have taken the year into consideration. But it was given that the table only contained  data for 2020. I had to solve the problem before I ran out of time, so I focused on just the month @jarlh

@gollapudisravani If you don't care about years, use the query in this answer. If you also need to group by year, extend the query. Check this sample fiddle to see the difference.

We can use conditional aggregation here for a general solution:
SELECT
    MONTH(Record_date) AS Month,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Data_type = 'min' THEN Data_value END) AS Min,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Data_type = 'max' THEN Data_value END) AS Max,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Data_type = 'avg' THEN Data_value END) AS Avg
FROM temperature_records
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;


Thank you for the answer. Asking this question just to confirm that I have understood the code correctly: So we group the temperature_records by their month and then the select is performed on each of these groups. So each of the aggregations is performed on the specific group right?  @Tim Biegeleisen

Correct...for each group of like month records, it selects the max over the data type column.  When the condition is true (for the matching row), it takes the max of the data value, otherwise it takes max of NULL, which is just ignored in the aggregation.

Is this what you wanted?
Try this,
Select * into #Temprecords from 
(Select '2020-07-01' Record_date, 'max' Data_Type, 92 Data_Value Union 
Select '2020-07-01' Record_date, 'min' Data_Type, 71 Data_Value Union 
Select '2020-07-01' Record_date, 'avg' Data_Type, 74 Data_Value Union 
Select '2020-07-02' Record_date, 'max' Data_Type, 90 Data_Value Union 
Select '2020-07-02' Record_date, 'min' Data_Type, 67 Data_Value Union 
Select '2020-07-02' Record_date, 'avg' Data_Type, 77 Data_Value ) A


;With Temprecords as   
(Select Month(Record_date) Mth
  ,Case Data_Type When 'min' Then min(Data_Value) Else 0 END as MinTemp
  ,Case Data_Type When 'max' Then max(Data_Value) Else 0 End as MaxTemp
  ,Case Data_Type When 'avg' Then avg(Data_Value) Else 0 End as AvgTemp
from #TempRecords
Group By Month(Record_date), Data_Type
)

Select Mth as 'Month', SUM(MinTemp) 'Min', SUM(MaxTemp) 'Max', SUM(AvgTemp) 'AVG'
From Temprecords 
Group By Mth
  
DROP table #TempRecords


I note the link is to a sql-server fiddle but the question is tagged mysql and the code is syntactically incorrect. https://dbfiddle.uk/mkSjiZ3f

:( missed to note it.
